# local reference does not reference

Tags: c++, reference

Reference as far as I know is a variable which holds an adress to an object.
Hence I do not understand this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

char* lol[]={"123","abc"};
char* fu(int i){return lol[i];};

int main ()
{
    const string& ru=fu(0);
    lol[0]="567";
    cout<<ru<<endl<<lol[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123
567
```

I was expecting

```
567
567
```

As I undersnand ru holds an adress to lol[0], so when I changed lol[0], ru had to return me that change.
Could anyone explain me why that is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fu` returns `char*`, but you use it to initialise a reference to a different type, `string`. This is resolved by creating a temporary `string`, containing a copy of string that the pointer refers to, and initialising the reference with that temporary. Changing `lol[0]` will not affect that string.

If you wanted a reference to the pointer `lol[0]`, then `fu` would have to return a reference, and `ru` would have to be a reference to the correct type:

```
char *& fu(int i){return lol[i];}

char *& ru = fu(0);
```

(By the way, you should be using `const char *` to point to string literals, since they are constant. The conversion to `char*` used to be allowed for historical reasons, but has been forbidden since 2011).

Comment: 1) so this code "const string& ru=fu(0);" creates in dynamical memory string object and returns to ru an adress? 2) Will that string object be deleted after the function from where ru was created will be completed? sorry for my English

Comment: 1) Almost - the temporary object will be on the stack, although it might allocate dynamic memory to contain the string data. 2) Yes, it has automatic lifetime, bound to the lifetime of the reference, and will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope. The code behaves exactly as if you'd written `const string ru = fu(0);` declaring an automatic variable rather than a reference bound to a temporary.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I'm fairly sure my answer is correct, but  I'd like to fix it if I've got something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help. btw It's not me downvoting you. I'd like to vote up you, but havent enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't behave as you expect, because the line

`const string& ru=fu(0);`

causes an implicit type conversion, meaning you've created a new string with its own buffer.

A `std::string` can't reference a `char*` (the types are incompatible) but the compiler can create a new `std::string` containing a copy of the `char*`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

`fu(0)` returns a copy of `lol[0]` rather than a reference to it. Try this:

```
std::vector<std::string> lol = { "123", "abc" };
std::string& fu(int i){ return lol[i]; };

const std::string &ru = fu(0);
lol[0] = "567";
std::cout << ru << std::endl << lol[0];
```

Using `std::string` is necessary because making a string reference out of a c-style string is logically impossible. They are two different types.